# Chained Selects jQuery with change jump menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, chained

I'm using the Chained Selects jQuery Plugin, http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

But i would like to add a jumpmenu to the second select element, i.e. go need to click submit. If i use the handler change, this is triggered upon the chained script.

```
  $(function(){
      $("#spotCat").chained("#locationCat"); 
      $("#spotCat").change(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
      });
  });
```

I'm not sure of the best way to get aroudn the problem? events triggered on click are fired when you "click" the select dropdown arrow?

Comment: I figured a nasty way to do it, but it doesn't feel good.

              $(function(){
              $("#spotCat").chained("#locationCat"); 
       $("#spotCat").change(function(){      
                this.blur()
       });
       $("#spotCat").blur(function(){
               window.location.href = $(this).val();
       });
          });

Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: i dont understand what you want to accomplish could you please explain more ..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way that plugin functions (specifically, the way it always leaves the first item selected when it populates the dependent option list), you just need to add one `if` to the anonymous `change` event handler function:

```
if ($(this).find("option:selected").index() !== 0) {
```

Demo (open your browser's developer tools and go to console to see when event logic fires-- or more to the point, when it does not fire):
http://jsfiddle.net/ywn6G/

The `if` in context:

```
$(function(){
    $("#spotCat").chained("#locationCat"); 
    $("#spotCat").change(function(){
        if ($(this).find("option:selected").index() !== 0) {
            window.location.href = $(this).val();
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: This way is nice, however the first option is always selected in the last option, so you can't click on that option to trigger the URL. I did come up with another solution which works, but wasn't very pretty, see below.

Comment: How does the user trigger the first item in the dependent list when it is already selected? By pulling down the options and then clicking the already-selected one? If so, that seems unintuitive and I might suggest putting "--", "Choose one" or the like as the first items instead, as in the demos on the Chained Select plugin's home page.

Answer (score 0):

The following way seems to work for me, it works because the blur event isn't triggered unless it's in focus. Which the change event doesn't give.

```
$(function(){
      $("#spotCat").chained("#locationCat"); 
  $("#spotCat").change(function(){      
        this.blur()
  });
  $("#spotCat").blur(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !== 0) {
          window.location.href = $(this).val();
        }
  });
```

});